# How to listen on resize of SplitPanel in JupyterLab?

Tags: javascript, jupyter-lab

I currently try to adapt some JupyterNotebook extension (https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/treezjs) for JupyterLab.

If the vertical SplitPanel is moved, I would like to update the size of my TreeView.

Unfortunately, the following code does not work. None of the events registers the movement of the vertical splitter:

```
app.shell.add(treezPlugin, 'left', { rank: 200 });

app.shell.layoutModified.connect(()=>{
    updateGoldenLayout(layout, layoutContainer);
}); 

app.shell.onResize(()=>{
    updateGoldenLayout(layout, layoutContainer);
}); 
        
window.onresize = ()=>{
    updateGoldenLayout(layout, layoutContainer);
};  

function updateGoldenLayout(layout, layoutContainer){
    var rect = layoutContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
    layout.updateSize(rect.width, rect.height);
}
```

The red area shows the horizontal size mismatch:

[image]

=> How can I correctly listen to changes of the horizontal SplitPanel?

I tried to access the SplitPanel but did not yet figure out how to do so.

Related:

https://github.com/golden-layout/golden-layout/issues/456

https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/seeking-suggestions-for-the-best-way-to-implement-a-split-view-jupyterlab-notebook-extension/2740

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/9269

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red div is my "layoutContainer". A ResizeObserver did the trick:

```
let resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver( () => {
   updateGoldenLayout(layout, layoutContainer);
});
resizeObserver.observe(layoutContainer);
```

Now I am able to use GoldenLayout for my JupyterLab extension

[image]